# How to create a DataFrame for an existing DataFrame column that is a JSON object?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to create a new dataframe from an existing dataframe where the main column of interest is a JSON object.

This is the structure of the object and the name of the column in the df is **"order_data"**

{
"id":"6069-281812814",
"items":[
{
"qty":"1",
"title":"Green Salad",
"toppings":[

```
     ],
     "additives":[
        
     ],
     "basePrice":"0.00",
     "unitPrice":"37.00",
     "updatedAt":0,
     "finalPrice":"37.00"
  },
  {
     "qty":"1",
     "title":"Salmon Piastra",
     "toppings":[
        
     ],
     "additives":[
        
     ],
     "basePrice":"0.00",
     "unitPrice":"92.00",
     "updatedAt":0,
     "finalPrice":"92.00"
  },
  {
     "qty":"1",
     "title":"Minted Lemonade Juice",
     "toppings":[
        
     ],
     "additives":[
        
     ],
     "basePrice":"0.00",
     "unitPrice":"23.00",
     "updatedAt":0,
     "finalPrice":"23.00"
  }
```

],
"amount":"121.60",
"subTotal":"0.00",
"table_id":"43",
"additives":[
{
"title":"Discount",
"value":"30.40",
"category":"discount",
"valueType":"",
"association":"inclusive"
},
{
"title":"_VAT",
"value":"0.00",
"category":"tax",
"valueType":"",
"association":"inclusive"
}
]
}

For the new dataframe, the ideal format should be as follows:

| order_id | item_name | finalPrice |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6069-281812814 | Green Salad | 37.00 |
| 6069-281812814 | Salmon Piastra | 92.00 |
| 6069-281812814 | Minted Lemonade Juice | 23.00 |

Thanks

I'm clueless on how to get to the desired format shown above.

Comment: Use `pd.json_normalize(json, 'items', 'id')`